# Headless Ubuntu - How do you do it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, headless, file-server

I would like to make my Ubuntu PC a headless file server.
How do I do that ?
Currently I have installed Ubuntu 10 LTS and it is all working fine.  I installed Webmin and can login remotely and administer the PC, but I would like to make it into a headless server and use its keyboard, mouse and monitor on another PC I am building.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Typically once you have it configured in a way that allows you to manage it remotely all you need to do is configure the BIOS to not halt on missing Keyboard, and unplug the Keyboard,Mouse,and Monitor.

You have the right idea with Webmin, however it might be beneficial to read up on SSH+Shell Commands, or if it's a desktop (graphical) install VNC or NoMachine.